# Azure Active Directory Restrict Groups Returning with Graph API

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-active-directory, restriction

We are trying to get list of users from a particular group in Azure Active Directory.

Steps tried:

1. Created new app registration
2. Created client secrets
3. Gave permissions for Graph API (application permissions) with admin consent.
4. Then we are getting all the users from all the groups.

Is there any way to restrict the app to only be able to return a specific group's users?

Comment: Is there any chance the particular groups you need to access are teams from Microsoft Teams?

Comment: Hi Philippe,
Thanks for looking into this.
Nope this is not for Microsoft Teams, its for some external application(Intelex).

Answer (score -1):

For **application permissions**, the effective permissions of your app are the **full** level of privileges implied by the permission. For example, an app that has the *User.ReadWrite.All* application permission can update the profile of every user in the organization, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#permission-types).

You could get the users in particular group with [List members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API, but the application still has the permissions for all groups.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/members
```

So far, it's only supported to control **mailbox** access of an app with [ApplicationAccessPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access).

Comment: Thanks for for the response Pamela. I know that by group id we can get list of users assigned to that group. But here still we will be able to access other groups and users also, which we don't want. Our app should able to read only one group and their members without exposing group other details such as group Id or name.

And the app should not able to access other groups.

So is there any way I can tell my registered app that only from this particular group users should be returned to API.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible as I said.